# How can I change my age verification to clear cookies every time a user enters my site?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am looking for a solution for my age check to display every time a user enters the site. Currently it is set to display once a day for a user. If they leave the site and comes back that day I need it display again. It is on Shopify.

```
           if ((today.getTime() - theirDate.getTime()) < 0) {
     window.location = 'http://google.com'; //enter domain url where you would like the underaged visitor to be sent to.
   } else {
     var days = 1; //number of days until they must go through the age checker again.
     var date = new Date();
     date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
     var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
     document.cookie = 'isAnAdult=true;'+expires+"; path=/";
     location.reload();
   };
```

Comment: session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting it to expire in one day, set it to expire after 0 seconds.

Comment: You want the cookie to expire immediately, requiring the user to verify their age every time they enter the site.